# Ошибка при добавлении данных в таблицу PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

В html выводится такая ошибка:
ОшибкаCannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`uchet`.`active`, CONSTRAINT `active_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_dep`) REFERENCES `department` (`id_dep`))
С чем это может быть связанно?

[image: база данных]

[image: связка базы]

Comment: Уберите эти скриншоты страшные.. Ошибка говорит о том что, в запросе, id_dep должно было быть значением id_dep с таблицы department

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вот код этих функций, я не могу понять в чем проблема. 
https://ibb.co/mNFhKLY