# Подскажите, почему в запросе SQL ошибка?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ошибка: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Код: на скрине.
Задача: Вывести форму, в которой из БД будут подгруженны данные. БЕЗ WHERE id_act='.$_GET['id_act']; Все работает, но выводится только первая запись из таблицы

[image: база данных]

[image: почему-то проблемный код]

[image: Ошибка на странице]

Comment: Ну так посмотрите итоговый запрос $query, может у вас там в $_GET['id_act'] мусор какой-нибудь или вообще ничего не пришло, тогда в запросе логично будет ошибка (особенно если пустое значение).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при добавлении данных в таблицу PHP/MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1287695/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-php-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с SQL-инъекциями и [подготовленными операторами SQL](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

```
<?php
// $_GET['id_act'] = 123;

$query = 'SELECT * FROM v_active WHERE id_act= ?;'; // SQL with parameters
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query); 
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['id_act']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
$item = $result->fetch_assoc(); // fetch data  

print_r($item);
```

[Test PHP online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=492b9d3308e307e2080cabb393b488d9&sqlses=e857ab2901305524c05751750fb7bc2f&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 0):

Конечно бы хотелось больше подробностей, например, что прилетает в var_dump($_GET['id_act']), но могу предположить, что вы обращаетесь к таблице **v_active**, а на скрине у вас просто **active** без V

```
'SELECT * FROM v_active WHERE id_act='.$_GET['id_act'];
```

соответственно попробуйте:

```
'SELECT * FROM active WHERE id_act='.$_GET['id_act'];
```